# Unlocking a Windows 10 session only to find it had rebooted

Tags: windows, windows-10

I normally finish the work day by putting my PC on Lock (Win key + L) so that I can leave all my documents and applications open. More and more often lately, I come back to the PC in the morning only to find that, after I log back in, the OS seems to have restarted, meaning all my apps and documents have to be reopened all over again.

This happens without any warnings or prompts having appeared the previous day.

Needless to say, this is very frustrating, and even more frustrating is to see that [previous reports](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello-winpc/why-does-my-computer-reboot-when-i-return-from/c81691ea-007a-4ae8-8c07-87314d8c88ac) of this behaviour from other users ellicit no helpful response from Microsoft.

My PC is running Windows 10, which I've set up (under Windows Update's Advanced Options) to have the system defer upgrades. Furthermore, it reboots even if there are no pending upgades. My PowerPlan options has the "Turn off hard disk after"option set to 'never'.

Any suggestions how to prevent this very unintelligent and annoying feature of Windows 10 would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you on a work computer? Check your user profile and see if you are on a remote one. If so, IT will reset everything at day end if on a remote profile.

Comment: It's not a remote profile, it's a personal PC, I just use it for work. Also, the reboots happen at random times, not always, although as I say, more and more frequently

Comment: Look for interesting messages in the Event Viewer. This can also be related to electric surges not under your control.

Comment: Windows automatically restarts for home users. This was a big debate and something I hate about it. I've lost work because of it. However, it does a good job of restoring most stuff these days, but not all.

In recent updates, there are options to defer updates for x amount of time. But this isn't perfect. I found that setting my connection to a metered connection helped. But Windows will still restart when it feels like it. That's the legacy of Bill Gates for you. :p

Comment: @harrymc: Among the events in the Event Viewer, I found one from WindowsUpdate, then from MSI_INstaller: ""Beginning a Windows Installer transaction: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\..\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.", followed by one from RestartManager: "Machine restart is required." . I guess it's then clear that the restart was due to a Windows Update. What's not clear is why this restarts the PC when the settings tell it not to...

Comment: Microsoft has vastly limited nowadays our control of Windows Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event Viewer show that an installation was instigated by Windows Update
at night, which is the default time for Windows Update.

If you wish to avoid that happening, you could instead of locking the screen
to put the computer to sleep. This will save your running state and in addition
the computer
will be protected from uncontrolled Windows Update restarts, and also from
power surges which might also cause a restart.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows updates wake your computer up when in sleep to install updates. This happened to me the other day. You can check in `cmd` with `powercfg –lastwake`. https://techjourney.net/prevent-disable-windows-update-from-waking-up-pc-system/

Comment: @InvariantChange: It's possible to [disable WU wakeup](https://techjourney.net/prevent-disable-windows-update-from-waking-up-pc-system/).

Comment: Yep, that's the same link I provided above!

Comment: @InvariantChange: Ah, yes, it is.